# Angular animations within same component

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-animations

Im trying to add animations to my entire website. The problem im facing is that within the same component, but a new route, my animation isn't working. I've set my animation up to activate when the route changes.

This is my routing setup:

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'not-found', component: PageNotFoundComponent},
      {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: { state: 'home'}},
      {path: 'stage', component: StageComponent, data: { state: 'stage'}},
      {path: 'documenten', component: DocumentenComponent, data: { state: 'documenten'}},
      {path: 'competenties/:uid', component: CompetentieComponent, data: { state: 'competenties/:uid'}}
];
```

This is my animation:

```
    export const routerTransition = trigger('routerTransition', [
    transition('* <=> *', [
        query(':enter, :leave', style({position: 'fixed', width: '100%'})
            , {optional: true}),
        group([
            query(':enter', [
                style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}),
                animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'}))
            ], {optional: true}),
            query(':leave', [
                style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'}),
                animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}
            ], {optional: true}),
        ])
    ]),
    ]);
```

This is the HTML used to call the animation

```
<div [@routerTransition]="getState(o)">
     <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

This is the TypeScript for the template:

```
import {routerTransition} from './animations';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    animations: [routerTransition]
})

export class AppComponent {
    public getState(outlet) {
        return outlet.activatedRouteData.state;
    }
}
```

I've tried using :increment as a transition but it doesn't seem to work. I'm completely new to the angular animations so any advice/help is appriciated!

Thanks!

Comment: check this:https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-router-animations

Comment: I've seen that and got my initial animations working. The problem when reloading the same component is the animation isnt working. The route changes but the component is the same, which messes up the animation process I think.

Comment: reloading meaning refresh the same page?

Comment: not refreshing, the onyl thing updating now is the view but I want to reload the component as the view is updated. I've tried creating a custom routereusestrategy but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Here is working code repository https://github.com/oleksiv/angular-animation-same-component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is component is reused and angular treat it as no change in this case and hence no transition animation is triggered.

This post provided a solution https://medium.com/frontend-coach/angular-router-animations-what-they-dont-tell-you-3d2737a7f20b

Comment: I was able to overcome this issue by simply hiding the top level div for the digest cycle with the following:
```this.pageState = PageState.LOADING; setTimeout(() => {this.pageState = PageState.READY; this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); });```